# Unity Project Settings goes back automatically

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I set my project settings, but when I revise some C# script added to game objects or run game-play mode, they roll back to former(maybe default) settings.

[image]

For example, when I set project settings like this, revise some C# script and come back to the Unity Editor, the settings are changed as below.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you aren’t changing them while the game is playing? Failing that report it to unity as a bug